# Can I convert every C++ lib into a header-only library?

Tags: c++, header-files

In C++ the library can be distributed in a header-only format. I am wondering if it's possible to convert every library into a header-only library? Or Vice Versa?
And what criteria should be used to decide whether I should distribute the library under header-only? Other than the header-only library has to be recompiled, is there any other considerations that might affect the decision? How does "inline" playing an import role here in header-only library?

Thanks,

Comment: Internal linkage seems like it wouldn't work in header only.

Comment: Even the notorious header-heavy BOOST library uses linked objects for the non-inlinable parts that don't depend on templates, so I'd go with their approach. The optimizer can't do that much magic that would depend on the call-site to large functions that aren't templated anyway…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, anything in a header is considered inline. This can be favorable for some libraries, but in general should be used with great consideration. Placing too much logic in a header can cause several undesirable consequences: inter-reliance of client code, long compilation times if the logic is ever changed, code bloat due to overuse of inline, and others. Some of these issues can be mitigated with a good optimizing compiler. In general I would recommend against placing complex logic in an inline function and hence in a header file, since its what causes the majority of these issues.

As for the reverse, yes, most libraries that are distributed as headers can be converted to a more traditional library. Exceptions to this would be libraries that are heavily reliant on templated code, as this is generally interpreted at compile time.

With regards to criteria, I would say that if the code is heavily templated and/or is primarily made up of simple functions then a header library would be an acceptable choice. Otherwise a normal library is almost definitely a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

In short, if you are fine with realeasing all source code, yes.

But there are many other things. If, for example, an update to a library is distributed, a dynamically-linked library will use the newest version, but the header only must recompile. Also, the other big difference is code optimization. When the compiler has access to the source, it can generate much better assembly for the specific situation.

Last, but not least, with dynamic-link you must have it installed in a library directory, but with header only your program can be independent.

Comment: Also the fact that not all libraries can be header only.  Namely, those that have a global.

Comment: many libraries use yet other libraries. Placing all code inline creates an onerous requirement on clients to import those libs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library whether or not its possible to convert it into header-only.  Conversely, any library could be converted from header-only to a traditional header+source.  You really want to ask yourself why do you want header-only?  What do you hope to gain or achieve?

Distributing a library as header only can cause you issues when it comes to library changes.  Lets say there's a small change that doesn't modify the interface.  Instead of recompiling the library, every application that uses it will have to be recompiled.  With a static library, user applications will simply have to be re-linked.  With a shared library, they don't have to be recompiled or re-linked.

You could also run into issues where every component using your library must use the same compiler and linker versions and be built similarly (ie, same CRT linkage, optimizations, etc) in order to communicate with library objects between each other.  But this could be largely handled with certain design choices.

With regard to "inline", everything is essentially inline with a header-only library.